# Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

I have been working on some self study "machine learning". Based on a few posts here, I wanted to make a program that "learned" via Bayes Law.  I test it with some simple truth tables. It recalls the past training data well. I note that some machines are able to make inferances in new situations, to different degrees. My particular version cannot do so, which raises a question.  Perhaps it doesn't learn, perhaps it only regurgitates.

My question is: In a broader, philosophical sense, does a program (any program) still qualify as "learning" if it cannot infer about things that it has not seen historically?  What are the bounds on such things?

Comment: If you do not provide us your code we cannot comment on it - it may be just a bug in the code that makes it not work as you'd like. We don't even know what your algorithm is! The fact that *your* algorithm does not work on *your* data does not mean that in general such algorithms do not work.

Comment: That's not the question, I accept that such algorithms work. The code above works perfectly as I would like. The question is: Can something (my code for instance) be said to learn if it cannot reason beyond past experiences?  What's the definition on learning?

Comment: Either case thank you for the question, You've allowed me to make a considerable improvement in clarity.

Answer (score 4):

Just my two cents. Generally, as you most likely know, *Bayesian networks* represent a *foundation* of a large subset of machine learning approaches, methods and algorithms. For example, see [this paper](http://www.eng.tau.ac.il/~bengal/BN.pdf). I think that the fact that your particular **implementation** of Bayesian inference/learning fails to produce correct probablities from your specific and particular **data set** does not really question Bayesian inference as a machine learning tool.

P.S. A note from the "terminology police" :-): in `R` , `bayes()` is not a *command* - it's a *function*.

Comment: Oh- Good point on function vs command. But that's not quite my question, I'm actually very happy with the implementation. 9000 draws might not be enough to get the probabilities perfect - the approach is very rudimentary!

Specifically: does it still "learn" if it it simply cannot ever infer a probability for row 3?

Comment: @RegressForward: I'm not sure about whether the code "learns" - I guess it depends on how you define "learning" in this context. I just find a bit odd that two probabilities "hover" around 0.5. Maybe that's OK, but maybe that reveals some issue with the code. Let's see what other people think about your question.

Comment: I improved the code so it does not resample with replacement. (Which is why it was only -close- the correct value, it grabbed a few too many samples of one sort rather than the other.)

Comment: @RegressForward: Great! I'm glad that you've figured it out. Thank you for the update (consider updating your question with the new code or posting it as an answer).